# Gradle installed but Cordova not seeing it

Tags: java, cordova, gradle, homebrew

When I install gradle 7.0, it automatically installs openjdk 15 but cordova requires openjdk 1.8. I uninstalled gradle then installed gradle 6.5 but it refuses to install. I also added gradle manually and added it to the environment variable path but cordova keeps insisting gradle is uninstalled. I checked the gradle version on the terminal and it exists. Can someone please help? How else do I install gradle?

/ % brew install gradle 6.5
Updating Homebrew...
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
These similarly named formulae were found:
cc65 ✔                     libde265                   x265
To install one of them, run (for example):
brew install cc65 ✔
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "6.5".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to [install Gradle creating the proper environment](https://www.andreszsogon.com/upgrading-gradle-version-for-apache-cordova-mobile-apps/) variable for the binary URL:

```
CORDOVA_ANDROID_GRADLE_DISTRIBUTION_URL
```

The local path must also be added to the `PATH` system variable.

Also, do not jump directly to latest Gradle version. Install the one that is required by your Cordova Android/iOS platform version.